# Prevent push to master from local into git

Tags: git, github

I want to prevent accidental push to master from my local. So there are many times where i have almost reached end accidentally to push into master from my local feature branch `git push origin master(here my it should be "my feature branch name")`.

So i just want to block this step in my local itself instead of any hooks in Github.

Comment: Are you calling you remote repository "master"? In that case you should stop. `master` is a branch (not a repo), and both your local repo and your remote repo probably have a branch called "master". You probably don't want to `git push origin master` from your local feature branch that is not `master`. A relevant workflow would be to `merge` your local feature branch into the local `master` branch, then push this local `master` branch to your remote repo `origin`.

Comment: Or if you want to push a feature branch before it is done, push it as a branch in the repo: `git push origin feature_branch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's muscle memory forcing you to type out `git push origin master`, and you only have one remote, then you should [switch your push style](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to only push the current branch instead.

You do this as follows:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

After that, all you need to do is push.  You'll push whatever branch you're on.

```
git push
```

Take care that this assumes if you're on master, you're going to be pushing master.  Otherwise, you'll be pushing whatever feature branch you're on.

Otherwise, it's a matter of self-discipline not to type out the entirety of the command.  It can be difficult at times to think that you should be pushing to master, but a quick double-check of what your command is actually doing is always better than any mechanical barrier could hope to be.

Comment: Isn't that the default? Anytime I push in a different branch it will try to push that branch's upstream branch, not master.